# Joint distribution of $n$ Bernoulli variables equal to binomial distribution, how?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is the joint distribution of $n$ Bernoulli variables equal to binomial distribution? I am confused by this questions and I would like to understand this. What about if Bernoulli variables dependent?

Comment: The **sum** of iid Bernoulli is binomial. Joint no (iid or not) except in the trivial case $n=1$.

Comment: The joint distribution of $n$ Bernoulli variables is a distribution on the set $\{0,1\}^n$. The binomial distribution is a distribution on the set $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$. Hence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint distribution of $n$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables is not the binomial distribution. The **sum** of $n$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables has the binomial distribution. If they are dependent, the distribution might not the binomial distribution.